# How to access specific data in a JSON response in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, networking

I have this JSON response when I run my swift program.

```
{
"success": true,
"info": "Groups",
"data": {
    "groups": "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test\",\"user_id\":1,\"active\":null,\"public\":true,\"image_file_name\":null,\"image_content_type\":null,\"image_file_size\":null,\"image_updated_at\":null,\"created_at\":\"2017-10-15T20:40:13.671+01:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-10-15T20:40:13.671+01:00\",\"hashtag\":null},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"test_again\",\"user_id\":1,\"active\":null,\"public\":false,\"image_file_name\":null,\"image_content_type\":null,\"image_file_size\":null,\"image_updated_at\":null,\"created_at\":\"2018-01-16T18:17:06.575+00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-01-16T18:17:06.575+00:00\",\"hashtag\":null}]"
}
```

However I want to access the information contained inside of "groups", specifically the id and name of the groups. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: groups corresponds to a string, and not a JSON array. (because its enclosed in quotes)

Extract the string, and then parse it as an array.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know, thanks

Comment: Just so you know, if you control the backend or the service in anyway or can approach the person responsible for it; ask them to not send it as a string. It breaks all conventions.

Comment: I actually do have access to the backend but I didn't write it myself and it's in rails so I wouldn't know how to go about changing it. If i were to change it would I send everything inside the string as nested responses instead?

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
let dic  = response["data"] as! [String:Any]

let groups = dic["groups"] as! String
```

then parse groups with jsonSerialization

and

```
let id  = data["id"]
```